# Replying with a image or gif obtained via API, in telegram bot python (telegram.ext)

Tags: python, api, telegram, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

I am building a meme generator telegram bot that sends a meme whenever the user commands /meme. I am using an API, say "https://......meme-api.....". It gives me a URL for the meme. I want to send the media in that URL provided by the API, as a reply to the /meme command.

```
dispatcher.add_handler(telegram.ext.CommandHandler("meme", meme))
```

```
def meme(update, context):
    response = requests.get('https://meme-api.herokuapp.com/gimme').json()
    url = response.get('url')
    print(url)
    update.message.reply_text(url)
```

I can't wrap my head around how I can write the meme function. What message reply type should I use to send the media without saving it?

Comment: Please detail what you have tried so far and which resources you have already consulted.

Comment: I have updated my question. It gives the URL, which shows the media but I want to send the media only without the URL. The module used is a telegram.ext and the API are BOTFATHER. The meme generator API is something I found on GitHub.

Comment: So you want to send the image using just the URL ?

Answer (score 1):

As explained in the documentation of [`Message.reply_text`](https://docs.python-telegram-bot.org/en/v13.14/telegram.message.html#telegram.Message.reply_text) that method is a shortcut for [`Bot.send_message`](https://docs.python-telegram-bot.org/en/v13.14/telegram.bot.html#telegram.Bot.send_message), which corresponds to [`sendMessage`](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#sendmessage) in the Telegram docs. This method sends text messages.
To send photos & animantions, you'll have to use

- [`Message.reply_photo`](https://docs.python-telegram-bot.org/en/v13.14/telegram.message.html#telegram.Message.reply_photo) / [`Bot.send_photo`](https://docs.python-telegram-bot.org/en/v13.14/telegram.bot.html#telegram.Bot.send_photo) / [`sendPhoto`](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#sendphoto)
- [`Message.reply_animantion`](https://docs.python-telegram-bot.org/en/v13.14/telegram.message.html#telegram.Message.reply_animation) / [`Bot.send_animantion`](https://docs.python-telegram-bot.org/en/v13.14/telegram.bot.html#telegram.Bot.send_animation) / [`sendAnimantion`](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#sendanimation),

respectively.